# PMD in gradle how to exclude directories

Tags: gradle, pmd

So I have set up PMD with in my gradle project.

I want to exclude certain directories from the scan?

How can i do that, this is my gradle setup

```
pmd {
    toolVersion = "6.48.0"
    sourceSets = listOf(java.sourceSets.findByName("main"))
    ruleSetFiles = files("/ruleset.xml")
}
```

Comment: maybe with something like `exclude '**/gen/**'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to exclude your java's application file from the task pmdMain, one way you could do that is by writing the following configuration:

```
pmd {
    toolVersion = "6.48.0"
    sourceSets = listOf(java.sourceSets.findByName("main"))
    ruleSetFiles = files("/ruleset.xml")
    pmdMain {
        excludes = [
                '**/name-of-your-application-file.java'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a hero. Bunch of examples of stackoverflow did not work, yours did. In my case it is a file